# Pc blacked out - how to resume vdb fluid Sim?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I was baking a heavy fluid Sim when some one turned of the fuse and of course my pc crashed without electricity. So after the fuse was back in, I checked and blender had produced already a lot of the vdb files, it was set to resumable. But when I try to load the directory in, blender trys baking from frame one instead like 260, which it Already had finished and which are in the Directory. Amy advise on how to properly reconnect the vdb's/ resume my project?

Comment: Im using Blender 3.61

Comment: Turning the power of in the middle of baking will almost certainly corrupt files and will not have saved any file that keeps track of how far the bake has progressed. That's probably why it's starting again from frame 1 and the only solution is to start again.

Comment: The Resume Fluid Bake addon may be able to help with this situation. It forces Blender to begin baking from a specified frame even after crashing, when there is no "Resume" button. https://blenderartists.org/t/resume-fluid-bake-add-on/1477869